# Flammable or Inflammable

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I am reading *The Elements of Style* and get stuck at the word *flammable*. There is the statement about the word:

> An oddity, chiefly useful in saving lives. The common word meaning "combustible" is *inflammable*. But some people are thrown off by the *in-* and think *inflammable* means "not combustible". For this reason, trucks carrying gasoline or explosive are now marked *flammable*. Unless you are operating such a truck and hence are concerned with the safety of children and illiterates, use *inflammable*.

Explanation above shows that flammable and inflammable have the same meaning actually. To avoid the misunderstand, people now use flammable to illustrate the danger, which easily be gotten from the last but one sentence. However the last sentence's meaning is contradictory to this, I think, and some helps or advice are needed here for comprehension. Thanks.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. The two words mean the same thing but "inflammable" is easily misunderstood. Sensible people, therefore, use "flammable" but the authors of *Elements of Style* don't want you to be sensible, because... well, I don't know why.

Comment: I think the quoted text is unnecessarily passive-aggressive about the issue. Especially considering that the majority of times that the word (in)flammable is going to be used **is** on warning signs where the meaning needs to be clear for safety reasons.

Comment: @nitro2k01: I'd go even further: I pretty much disagree with the sentence quoted but I still think Hellion's answer is correct because it accurately states what it means :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Indeed. I wasn't disputing Hellion's answer, but rather commenting on the quoted guideline in general. I do agree that his answer is the most appropriate because it exactly answers what was asked.

Comment: @nitro2k01: yeah, I just meant to add that it isn't merely stated in a passive-aggressive way, it's probably bad advice even absent any safety concerns. Which isn't too surprising, any judgement made on the basis of what is "common" will date.

Comment: Kind of surprised nobody has posted [this](http://youtu.be/efDYvtj2Rlo) yet. “‘Inflammable’ means ‘flammable’? What a country!”

Comment: In my dialect, I'd call the authors' attitude as displayed in that last sentence "snotty".

Comment: @swbarnes2 +1 Agreed. I find it gratifying that Hellion's answer has been accepted (as well it should be, it directly answered the OP's question, I upvoted it for that reason) But my answer, which addresses the idiocy of what the text is saying continues to garner upvotes. This community pretty clearly agrees that "inflammable" is an unnecessary word in the English language.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung You beat me too it.

Comment: While I yield to no-one in my aversion to White's strictures, I think it only fair to point out that in 1957, when White originally wrote this, "flammable" was very much a neologism, as may be seen in this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flammable%2Finflammable%2Cinflammable%2Finflammable&year_start=1900&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28flammable%20/%20inflammable%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28inflammable%20/%20inflammable%29%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paragraph says basically that the use of "flammable" is purposely "dumbing down" your language in order to cater to uneducated people, and that is a bad thing, so you should avoid doing it (unless you NEED to do so for some specific reason).

Answer (score 23):

Flammable is replacing inflammable for exactly the reason suggested in that quote. There is no harm in it, flammable works just as well in any context in which you might say inflammable. In my opinion, the last sentence of that quote is unnecessary and I get no heartburn from the idea that flammable will ultimately replace inflammable in the English language. I completely agree with Hellion, his explanation says exactly what the author of the text is trying to say. I just disagree with the final line of the  text.

EDIT: By the way, I remember asking that as a kid. "Why does this say that gasoline doesn't burn?" I was prone to experimentation as a kid too. Hmm, good thing I asked! :)

Further EDIT: Great quote from [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/flammable-versus-inflammable): "Flammable" and "inflammable" mean the same thing; they both mean "easy to burn." "Inflammable" is the original word, but then in the 1920s, according to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage, the National Fire Protection Association started encouraging people to use the word "flammable" instead because they were worried people could mistakenly think "inflammable" meant "not flammable." They saw it as a safety issue. Academics were inflamed (get it?) because they didn't appreciate the Fire Protection Association messing with the language and promoting "corrupt" words. Perhaps they thought dumb people should die a firey death if they went around holding matches to inflammable objects. Regardless, linguists have groused about "flammable" in usage books ever since.

Comment: +1 I agree when both the words mean same, why use something that creates ambiguity?

Comment: Particularly when a misunderstanding could be dangerous.

Comment: "I get no heartburn";  because your heart is uninflammable or because it's unflammable? ;)

Comment: Because it's made of stone.

Comment: Maybe because it is not combustible?

Comment: That's probably a good thing.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Because it's non-flammable.

Comment: I'm copying this here because it is very relevant: 
   
 
Useful to note that (according to Google Ngrams) usage of flammable surpassed that of inflammable in 1971. The Elements Of Style is all very well, but inflammable is clearly on the way out. –  benshepherd 5 hours ago -- benshepherd's original link is active on Maulik V's answer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Be cautious! When you use 'inflame' for the body organ, it's swelling :) My knee joint is inflamed!

Answer (score 10):

A good question, indeed.

[Here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/flammable-versus-inflammable) I found something very useful that says...

> "Inflammable" is the original word, but then in the 1920s, according to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage, the National Fire Protection Association started encouraging people to use the word "flammable" instead because they were worried people could mistakenly think "inflammable" meant "not flammable."

Basically, the prefix *in*-in *inflammable* is the Latin preposition which means *en-*, not *un-* which is used in negation. Making inflammable flammable makes sense to me as it avoids ambiguity for children and illiterates. Also, literates do know 'flammable' is 'flammable' so using a word that **everybody** understands is **okay**.

Here is the [list of Latin roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English) where you find English *in* and its root *en-* and *in (negative) and its root *un-*.

Comment: Useful to note that (according to Google Ngrams) [usage of _flammable_ surpassed that of _inflammable_ in 1971](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flammable%2Cinflammable&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cflammable%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bflammable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFlammable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFLAMMABLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cinflammable%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binflammable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInflammable%3B%2Cc0). _The Elements Of Style_ is all very well, but _inflammable_ is clearly on the way out.

Answer (score 6):

Note that combustible is *not* the same as (in)flammable:

- combustible means that a substance can burn or be burned.
- (in)flammable means that it is easy to start the combustion

While people mix these meanings in everyday language (see below), I find it odd in a text concerned about precision of language.

As a chemist, I'd always use *flammable* without *in* 
- this is unambiguous, which is particularly good for words that are "useful in saving lives"
  For the negation, not flammable is unambiguous as well.
- This is also the term used in the corresponding regulations.

That being said, there is of course nothing wrong with knowing the foreign roots of terms, how language developed and about false friends (also within one language). But as others have noted, languages do develop.

At least in French and Italian the corresponding words do not differentiate (much) between combustible and the ease of starting the combustion (ignition).
German instead uses "entzündlich" which would literally correspond to ignitable (though that again has a slightly different meaning - German would be "zündfähig"). AFAIK important regulations (including the terms for metioned gasoline truck) are largely influenced by the DIN (German industrial norms) and thus make differentiations which are "natural" in German language and which are of practical importance. After all, the risks associated with a truck full of wood and a truck full of gasoline are quite different. And language is largely about communication (particularly on a lanugage learners site).

Comment: I almost said (about) the same thing. Inflammable has always meant dangerously so to me. As if flammable meant burnable while inflammable meant explosive. I was pretty sure of my answer, and I then tried to find documentation to back me up. At least in the first 5 references, I couldn't find it. I think the earliest changes took place while we weren't watching.

Comment: When I packed boxes for shipment many years ago, distinct markings were required for "combustible", "flammable liquid" and "flammable gas", and they could not be combined within a shipment.  I don't know how the handling of the packages differed once I sent them down the conveyor, but at least from a shipping perspective, "combustible" and "flammable" were not the same thing.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: "I almost said (about) the same thing" that's why I upvoted your answer. But I wanted to add the information about combustibility vs. flammability as well and add a technical terminology perspective that I think is important for everyday life. Explosive is still different.

Comment: @supercat: flammable substances are always combustible (like highly flammable substances always also meet the definition of flammable). But not every combustible substance is flammable, and not every flammable substance is highly flammable.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: I don't understand what you mean by changes when we weren't watching.

Comment: I really think we are at a point (in common English, not technical) that the two words are interchangeable. Personally, I think that's a good thing. Technical language will always be different.

Comment: @cbeleites What I mean is that the word inflammable no longer means what it used to. It was 40 years ago that I first brought up the question with my mother. Since then, the word has slipped away in common usage.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: As for references, the German Wikipedia page http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gefahrensymbol#.C3.9Cbersicht_Gefahrensymbole on hazard symbols has English terms as well as links to definitions (then it becomes purely German, though). It's English pendant doesn't have anything the like unfortunately.

Comment: In English, hazard symbols and the like have completely abandoned "inflammable". It's as if "inflammable" was never a word.

Comment: Hey, language changes over time, sometimes for the better. If there is a danger of the "in-" prefix confusing the general public (not a difficult thing to do!), why not change to just "flammable"? The only hazard will be that people seeing the odd leftover "inflammable" here and there, might not understand it!

Answer (score 4):

The prefix "in" typically means to [negate the root word](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/in_20). However some word in english have differing origins and therefore do not all follow the same construction rules.

"Inflammable" is one case where the rule above does not apply. Due to the prevalence of the rule being true many less english savvy speakers apply the rule to "inflammable" and think it means "not combustible". Normally a mistake like this would be laughed off but with the dire consequence of getting this one word wrong most safety warning are opting to use "flammable".

So `"Unless you are operating such a truck and hence are concerned with the safety of children and illiterates, use inflammable."` is stating that if your purpose of writing is to inform of danger use "flammable" because it's less likely to cause injury. For all other reasons use "inflammable" as it is the correct word for educated discourse.

Comment: Basically, the prefix in-in inflammable is the Latin preposition which means en-, not un- which is used in negation

Comment: "Less english savvy speakers" with roman native languages (e.g. French inflammable, Italian infiammabile, Spanish inflamable) of course do not have this difficulty. However, afaik they all share the difficulty that these words are ambiguous with respect to difference between combustible and ease of ignition.

Comment: Mind you, it would be awesome if "indubitable" did mean "capable of being put to doubt" just as "inflammable" means "capable of being set on fire" :-) @cbeleites: surely the same ambiguity for "in-" exists in French? "inflammable" vs "incroyable"? I'm not claiming there's misunderstanding what "inflammable" means among French speakers, I don't know. Just that both meanings of "in-" exist and so they could be in doubt, if they wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The final sentence is a sardonic retort, suggesting that if you *want* to cause someone harm, you may use "inflammable".

A similar example would be:

> Feel free to drop your cigarette on the floor, yeah. Even in this forest, at the hottest time of year. If you don't mind setting fire to thousands of square acres and rendering countless hundreds of people homeless, that is...

Comment: You think so? I read it just the opposite way: For ordinary audiences you should use *inflammable*. Use *flammable* only if both the probability and consequences of misunderstanding *inflammable* are high.

Comment: @StoneyB: That's certainly your prerogative. On the other hand, I, as a native speaker of English, i.e. being from England, have a full understanding and appreciation of its power of sarcasm and so forth.

Comment: Oh, I think there's sarcasm there, I just think, from what I know of White (I decline to attach any blame to poor Strunk), that it's directed the other way: "Feel free to trample flat-footedly on My English if you are one of the Infantine and Imbecilic Cretins to whom Linguistic Purity is a Closed Book."

Answer (score 1):

really flammable or inflammable mean the same .   first I thought that flammable is the opposite of inflammable but the opposite of flammable or inflammable is non flammable.

Comment: This simply repeats the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

gasoline trucks used to carry signs stating their contents were flammable and imflammable. This meant that not only were the contents combustible but that they would cause other substances to also combust. The prefix "im-" carried that narrow sense. Analogous usage would be in other words carrying the "im-" prefix, though by no means all with that prefix nor only with it. E.g., "en-gulf" or engulf, uses a version of the Latin "im/n," and there are other instances. Interestingly, however, though one can find evidence of this narrow usage online (usually with bewildered commentary), authoritative references don't include it, not even the OED, which does have a very useful list of other English words with the "im-" prefix describing the outward effect of the word. One can find (using DuckDuckGo, Google and other search engines) instances of writers dismissing "imflammable" as misspelled "inflammable" but I think they miss how it was intended: to signify that not only was the agent, like gasoline, prone to catch fire, but that it could also set other things on fire, too. It would seem that the usage failed to gain popularity or succeeded in being a puzzle. At any rate, it's nigh impossible to find current instances of "imflammable" today; one sees it understood as "inflammable," meaning only that the substance itself is combustible and not that it can also engulf others in flame or, more succinctly, inflame.